# Bootstrap две вкладки в модальном окне с динамическими формами

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть страница в которой вызывается модальное окно. В модальном окне есть две вкладки tab. По идее, в каждой из них должна быть отдельная динамическая форма, с возможностью клонирования полей, но при реализации получается, что все время, при переключении между вкладками, показывается только первая форма из первой вкладки. Как сделать, чтобы в каждой вкладке была своя динамическая форма?

Я использовал [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/u55szysh/8/) для реализации собственного решения с клонирование полей. Изменил для каждой формы названия полей, названия слоев и идентификатор формы, а весь остальной код оставил без изменений из примера.

**Моя форма для клонирования**

```
<!-- script id="template_add_form" type="text/template" -->
  <div class="entry input-group triple-input">
      <select class="form-control" name="material" >
          <option>...</option>
      </select>     
      <select class="form-control" name="cena" >
          <option>..</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" placeholder="..." name="kol" class="form-control" />

      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button" name="button" id="cloneButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
      </span>
  </div>
<!--//script-->
<form method="post" id="loanform" role="form" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="entries"></div>
</form>
```

**Код обработчика**

```
$(function() {
    //console.log($('#template_add_form'));
    var clone = function(tmpl) {
            return $((tmpl.clone()).html())
        },
        $template = $('#template_add_form'),
        formArray = [ clone($template) ], // init array with first row
        $formEntries = $('#entries');

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
        //console.log('clicked');
        formArray.push(clone($template));
        updateForm();
        // set focus to adding row = last element in array
        $(formArray).last()[0]
            .find('input')
            .first()
            .focus();
    });

    // remove not working yet
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(evt) {
        var id;
        // iterate over formArray to find the currently clicked row
        $.each(formArray, function(index, row) {
            //console.log(index, row.has(evt.currentTarget).length);
            if ( row.has(evt.currentTarget).length == 1 ) {
                //console.log(row.has(evt.currentTarget));
                id = index; // click target in current row
                return false; // exit each loop
            }
        });

        //console.log('clicked', id);
        formArray.splice(id, 1);
        updateForm();
    });

    var updateForm = function() {
        // redraw form --> problem values are cleared!!
        //console.log(formArray);
        var lastIndex = formArray.length - 1,
            name; // stores current name of input

        $formEntries.empty(); // clear entries from DOM becaue we re-create them
        $.each(formArray, function(index, $input) {
            //console.log(index, $input);
            // update names of inputs and add index
            //console.log('inputs', $input.find('input'));
            $.each($input.find('input'), function(inputIndex, input) {
                name = $(input).attr('name').replace(/\d+/g, ''); // remove ids
                $(input).attr('name', name + index);
            });

            if (index < lastIndex) {
                // not last element --> change button to minus
                //console.log($input.find('.btn-add'));
                $input.find('.btn-add')
                     .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                     .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                     .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
            }
            $formEntries.append($input);
        });
    };

    updateForm(); // first init. of form

    $('form#loanform').submit(function(evt) { 
        evt.preventDefault();
        var fields = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
            //console.log(field.name);
            //if ( field.name == 'extra' ) {
            //    console.log('extra', field.name, field.value);
            // }
            if ( field.name.contains('material') ) 
            {   // field.name contains balance
                console.log('material', field.name, field.value);
                // now you can do your calculation
            }
            if ( field.name.contains('cena') )
            {   // field.name contains balance
                console.log('cena', field.name, field.value);
                // now you can do your calculation
            }
            if ( field.name.contains('kol') )
            {   // field.name contains balance
                console.log('kol', field.name, field.value);
                // now you can do your calculation
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Во второй форме два поля, поэтому сократил число полей, заменил название в обработчике `field.name.contains('..')`, а также заменил как в обработчике, так и в HTML-коде `#template_add_form` на `#template_rab_form`,  `#entries` на `#rab`, `form#loanform` на `form#rab`, но реально это не помогло. Две вкладки, две формы, а при переключении все равно показывает первую форму с первой вкладки. Как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще вопрос по ходу, как изменять имя поля в новыых, динамически добавляемых?

```
if ( field.name.contains('name') )
    {   
        console.log('name', field.name, field.value);
        // now you can do your calculation
    }
```

---

Я выложил код всего  [модального окна](http://jsfiddle.net/usoez1td/2/).

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" >
```

Comment: код невалиден, теги не закрыты.

Comment: @leks, спасибо за ответ. Здесь только фрагмент кода, все модальное окно (которое выложил на jsfiddle) перепахал, не могу найти... какие теги не закрыты, подскажите?

Comment: перед `<!--// MATERIALS-->` не хватает `</div>`, таб работать начинает, но форма не выводится. Вынесите js код и отладьте нормально.

Comment: `$formEntries = $('#rb');` а в html `id="rab"` - исправить и заработает. Мусора в коде много, отсюда и ошибки. PS не за что.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста помогли ли Вам ответы в комментариях, или проблема сохраняется?

Comment: @leks оформите Ваши комментарии как ответ